# ASP.NET MVC 4 beta - script inside a section - `{` missing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a script section in my _layout shared view in order to add script to a view as required.
after upgrading to MVC 4 beta, the MVC wont identify the closing } of the the section and i get an error.
I saw other threads saying to use `@(Html.Raw("});"))` (i am using JQuery). This is not a good solution as i have over 30 closing `}` in my section.

I can put the script in a JS file but that is not a good solution.

Any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I'm running into the same thing right now and after a lot of experimentation, it looks like it's the result of some sort of Razor interpreter bug resulting from the `for` loop I have in the `@section ScriptSection {`. My loop is completely standard:

```
for (var i = 0; i < viewModel.questions.length; i++) {
...
}
```

but after removing it, Razor finds my ending `}` properly. I don't know why but it apparently thinks that the `<` is starting a tag. After changing my loop code to look like:

```
for (var i = 0; viewModel.questions.length > i; i++) {
```

everything worked fine. I know that something else is probably contributing to this, because it worked fine for a while and then broke. Hopefully this helps.